# Help with this equivalence in this exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. I would like a hint how to prove these statements are equivalent:

1. There are a group $K$ and a homomorphism $p:G\to K$ such that $H$ is the kernel of $p$.
2. For every $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, we have $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: Using 2, can you create a natural mapping from $G$ to $G/H$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) Prove that the kernel of **any homomorphism** $\;\rho:G\to K\;$ is always a *normal subgroup*.

b) Show that if $\;H\lhd G\;$ , then $\;H=\ker\rho\;$ , with $\;\rho:G\to G/H\;$ , the canonical projection, meaning:

$$\rho x:= xH\in G/H\;,\;\;x\in G$$

Pay attention to the fact that with this exercise you've proved a subgroup of $\;G\;$ is normal iff it is the kernel of some homomorphism from $\;G\;$ to some other group.